# React Quill infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm encountering an issue with the React Quill editor. Whenever I attempt to set a state in the parent component of my editor, I end up stuck in an infinite loop.

the state in question is defined below :

```
const [content, setContent] = useState({
    shortDescription: "hello",
    description: "",
    category: "",
    title: "",
    level: "",
    originalPrice: 0,
    discountedPrice: 0,
    difficulty: "",
    language: "",
    requirements: "",
    learningElement: "",
  });
```

The editor is defined below :

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

function Editor({onEditorChange,code}) {

  
  const modules = {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
      ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
      [{ size: [] }],
      [{ font: [] }],
      [{ align: ["right", "center", "justify"] }],
      [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
      ["link", "image"],
      [{ color: ["red", "#785412"] }],
      [{ background: ["red", "#785412"] }],
    ],
  };

  const formats = [
    "header",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "underline",
    "strike",
    "blockquote",
    "list",
    "bullet",
    "link",
    "color",
    "image",
    "background",
    "align",
    "size",
    "font",
  ];



  return (
    <>
      {console.log(code)}
      <ReactQuill
        theme="snow"
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        value={code}
        onChange={onEditorChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Editor;
```

The infinite loop occurs within the following code block :

```
<div className="col-12">
                    <label className="text-16 lh-1 fw-500 text-dark-1 mb-10">
                      Short Description*
                    </label>
                    <Editor
                      code={content.shortDescription}
                      onEditorChange={(content, delta, source, editor)=>{
                        const newShortDescription = editor.getText();
                        setContent((prevContent) => ({
                          ...prevContent,
                          shortDescription: newShortDescription,
                        }));
                      }}                        
                  
                    ></Editor>
                  </div>
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated !